# How to eliminate elements with certain characters or phrases from a list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, list

I have a list of plant names from an excel spreadsheet that I have extracted with pandas. After removing duplicates and making the entire list lower-case, I wanted to remove characters like parenthesis, apostrophes, dashes, and phrases like "A" and "The" to further eliminate any possible duplicates so that in a list like: `("A Pumpkin", "Pumpkin", "The Pumpkin", "Pump-kin", "(European) Pumpkin", "Pumpkin (Orange)", "Farmer's Pumpkin")` only "Pumpkin" would remain. Note I don't want to remove just the characters from the string, but the entire string from the list.

```
def checkSyntax(str):
    boolean = None

    regexes = ["a ", "the ", "^\W"]
    combined = "(" + ")|(".join(regexes) + ")"
    match = re.match('combined', str)
    if match == None:
        boolean = True

    return boolean

def elimInvalidNames(names):
    new_names = [s for s in names if checkSyntax(s)]
    return new_names 

test_list = ("A Pumpkin", "Pumpkin", "The Pumpkin", "Pump-kin", "(European) Pumpkin", "Pumpkin (Orange)", "Farmer's Pumpkin")
test_list = list(map(lambda x: x.lower(), test_list))
test_list = elimInvalidNames(test_list)
print(test_list)
```

For some reason this gets rid of "the" and "a" but not parenthesis, dashes, or apostrophes.

Comment: How would the program know whether to keep `Farmer` or `Pumpkin`?

Comment: It should remove any element that contains an apostrophe so "Farmer's Pumpkin" would be removed because it has a '.

Comment: Do you only want to return a single word, or are there supposed to situations where it should return multiple words?

Comment: `re.match` only matches from the beginning of the string. Check out the documentation on [search vs match](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#search-vs-match)

Comment: That was just for the example but the actual list has thousands of plants. The actual list has a lot of duplicates like the example above.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
import re
new = []
test_list = ("A Pumpkin", "Pumpkin", "The Pumpkin", "Pump-kin", "(European) Pumpkin", "Pumpkin (Orange)", "Farmer's Pumpkin")
for s in test_list:
    for n in s.split():
        if n == re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',n) and n.lower() != 'a' and n.lower() != 'the': # Adds word to new list if word is not 'a', 'the', and doesn't contain punctuations 
            new.append(n)
print(list(set(new))) # Convert to a set to remove duplicates, then back to alis
```

Output:

```
['Pumpkin']
```

Answer (score 0):

If regex is not mandatory be used, try it:

```py
names = ("A Pumpkin", "Pumpkin", "The Pumpkin", "Pump-kin", "(European) Pumpkin", "Pumpkin (Orange)", "Farmer's Pumpkin")
def checkSyntax(s):
    regexes = ["a ", "the ",'"', "'", '\\', '.', ',', ')', '(', '-']
    return not any(letra in s.lower() for letra in regexes)

def eIn(names):
    new_names = [s for s in names if checkSyntax(s)]
    return new_names
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regular expressions, then use `re.search` as this will attempt to match the expression at any part of the string. The `re.match` function only attempts to match the expression at the start of the string.

For example, the following code filters the list to `['Pumpkin']`:

```
import re
invalid_names_re = re.compile(r"(A )|(The )|[()\-']", re.IGNORECASE)                                                                                                                                                            names = ("A Pumpkin", "Pumpkin", "The Pumpkin", "Pump-kin", "(European) Pumpkin", "Pumpkin (Orange)", "Farmer's Pumpkin")  

filtered_names = [name for name in names if not invalid_names_re.search(name)]
```